# Is there a real gain in terms of security by not using a reverse proxy?

Tags: network, proxy, architecture, dmz

I need to implement a web application consisting of the components

- FE (Nginx + React.js)
- BE (Java SpringBoot)
- DB (MySQL)

For simplicity we will assume that the DB runs in localhost on BE's machine.

From an architectural point of view, I imagine the following configuration:

> **FE <--> DMZ <--> BE**

I need to deploy BE and FE on two different machines (from the requirement), and I am trying to analyse in terms of security the pros and cons of using a reverse proxy.

Does it really make sense to use a reverse proxy? Given the use of a reverse proxy, the FE would not be an additional layer of protection (e.g. input sanitisation, endpoint masking, use of a subset of endpoints), but just a transparent layer.

In an attack scenario, attacking an endpoint managed by a reverse proxy, would be equivalent to attacking the backend, thus simply bypassing the DMZ.

Whereas in a configuration where the front-end receives requests from clients, and sends independent requests (no reverse proxy) to the BE, the scenario would change completely (see points listed above).

So my question is:

- Is there a real gain in terms of security by not using a reverse proxy?

Comment: 1) Do you mean, that Nginx is running outside of DMZ?

Comment: 2) Do you mean that Nginx is forwarding requests to the Spring Boot application? If yes, then Nginx is reverse proxy. What other reverse proxy you mean?

Comment: 1) Yes, Nginx is running outside of DMZ. The other choice is to build a little script on FE that send requests directly to BE, without reverse proxy, in an attack scenario BE will not be attacked directly (as per reverse proxy configuration), and an attacker doesnt interact directly with "behind DMZ" environment.
So my question is: there is a real gain in terms of security by not using a reverse proxy today (given new technologies, patterns and best practices)?

Comment: It depends. For instance, if you have WAF in Ngnix, it will provide an additional security layer. If BE is reachable from the internet directly, without WAF, you don't have this kind of protection.